# Как загрузить изображение в VK

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, vkontakte-api, axios

Есть ссылка на изображение, хочу получить его и загрузить в вк для отправки.
Текущий код:

```
                                axios
                                .get(response.data.data.url, {responseType: 'stream'})
                                .then(response => {
                                    let formData = new FormData()

                                    formData.append('photo', response.data)
                                    let data = response.data
                                    axios
                                        .get('https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getMessagesUploadServer?peer_id=59820054&access_token=токен&v=5.92')
                                        .then(response => {
                                            axios
                                                .post(response.data.response.upload_url, formData, {
                                                    headers: {
                                                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                                                    }
                                                })
                                                .then(response => {
                                                    console.log(response.data)
                                                })
                                        })
                                })
                            ctx.reply('', response.data.data.url)
```

В ответ получаю

```
{ server: 845420,
  photo: '[]',
  hash: '34f3c5bf70d290d249b358727f91dd3c' }
```

Насколько понимаю как-то не правильно прикрепляю изображение к POST запросу. В чем ошибка?

Comment: в formData для photo нужно обязательно указать имя файла (но как это делается в node.js, я не знаю)

Comment: Уже делал так, к тому же пробую отправить через postman так приходит пустой массив photo

Comment: Ошибься, через postman все ок